# Display.getDefault().asyncExec not running correctly

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse's jobs API to run big task as a job, once task is completed I am setting boolean variable to true and if that variable is true I am executing WizardDialog in UI thread. My current code looks like this:

```
Job longRunningJob = new Job("Long running job...") {
    @Override
    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {

        boolean shouldShowDialog = doLongRunningJob();

        if(shouldShowDialog) {
          Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                    //Will open wizard dialog here
                    WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), new TestWizard());
                    wizardDialog.setBlockOnOpen(true);
                    wizardDialog.open();
               }
          });
        }
    }
}

longRunningJob.setUser(true);
longRunningJob.schedule();
```

My problem is `run` inside Display thread not executing in reliable way, means sometime it goes inside run method where as sometimes it doesn't, I tried putting breakpoint inside `run` method and testing it out but same happens.

My question is, is what I am doing is correct way? Is this expected behaviour? So how do I handle this scenario ie once `shouldShowDialog` is true how do I execute code inside Display thread?

**Edit**: One behaviour I observed while debugging is dialog gets displayed but suddenly it get closes, I think it's exiting the thread.

Comment: This is a very common pattern in Eclipse, never seen it go wrong.

Comment: @greg-449, the problem what's happening is dialog is getting displayed but suddenly closes.

Comment: Post the code which creates the dialog.

Comment: @MarttiKäärik, just now edited question.

Comment: Check the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for messages

Comment: @greg-449, checked no error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with disappearing dialogs is most commonly caused by using currently active Shell as the parent for the dialog. E.g. if there is a ProgressDialog open when you create your dialog then that other dialog will be the parent of your dialog. And when the other dialog closes, so does yours.

Instead, use something like:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, so any tips on how to handle such scenarios?

Comment: @PradeepSimha Added example.