# Display.getDefault.syncExec() not running correctly in headless mode

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm running my application in headless mode and for some execution i need to display a dialog in between for some specified time.

**Code Sample**

```
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
       //Jface Dialog code
       RuntimePauseDialog dlg = new RuntimePauseDialog();
       dialogResult = dlg.open();
    }
});
```

The above code will be called multiple times and for the first time the Dialog appears. From 2nd time onwards the dialog doesn't show up. Moreover run() will not be executed at all and freezes. Inside syncExec() there is a Runnable lock which gets initialized and calls wait(), which waits forever (Application freezes)
I think this has something to do with Threads.

**Note :** The same code displays the dialog (multiple times) correctly when run from UI mode. The problem is only in headless mode.

Tried this suggestion from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781759/display-getdefault-asyncexec-not-running-correctly), but since i'm running in headless mode, there will be no Workbench created and cannot use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`syncExec` (and `asyncExec`) relies on there being a main `Display.readAndDispatch` loop running in the UI thread. In headless mode this is not the case so this is simply not going to work at all.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 for the reply, but still would like to know how it is coming up for the first time and not the second time ?

Comment: That would require a lot of debugging. On macOS (which I use) this code doesn't run at all failing immediately with a 'Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions' error.

Comment: Display.getDefault() Java doc says
_"returns the default display, else one is created, making the thread that invokes this method its user-interface thread if it did not already exist"_

Does it create a display in headless mode ?

Comment: `Display` doesn't know anything about headless mode so, yes, it will try to create the display - but nothing will call `readAndDispatch` and on some platforms the create will fail.